# How can I pull data from a program currently running on my computer using Python?

Tags: python

How do I pull data from an app?  I have a phone app, when the call comes in, I want to be able to copy the phone number that appears.

Comment: Where does the number appear?  What do you want to do with it?

Comment: It's not so simple, we need more info

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question as it is a fundamental one.

The app that knows the phone number is able to know it because it owns the memory holding that piece of data. No other process is able to read that piece of memory.

You have to explicitly set up interprocess communication (IPC) to achieve what you want. This is a deep topic on its own so there is no one easy answer based on the description of the problem you gave.